# Font used in ACM template

Tags: fonts, acm

does anyone know what is the font used by the new ACM paper template/class? I want to create a class for my dissertation and I really like this font.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Jorge

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. A suggest in these links: https://www.acm.org/publications/taps/whitelist-of-latex-packages (most recent) and https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/acm-official#.WOuOk2e1taQ

Comment: Found it! The name is Libertine

Comment: I am happy to help you :-).

Answer (score 16):

`acmart` uses Libertine for text, Inconsolata for monospaced font and newtxmath for math.  The code you need is

1. For pdftex

   \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \RequirePackage[tt=false, type1=true]{libertine}
   \RequirePackage[varqu]{zi4}
   \RequirePackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
2. For xetex change this to to

   \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
     \RequirePackage[tt=false]{libertine}
     \setmonofont{inconsolata}
     \RequirePackage[varqu]{zi4}
     \RequirePackage[libertine]{newtxmath}