# Help need finding the exact typeface

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, typography

I'm trying to find the exact same font used in [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2022/05/ICSE.pdf) document. I tried finding it using online font-search tools by providing PNGs. But could not find the precise typeface.

I also suspect it could be one of the typefaces provided here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_typefaces

I can see the fonts in the document properties, but not sure what those points to the actual typeface.
[image]

Screenshot of the typeface I'm searching for, related to the [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2022/05/ICSE.pdf),
[image]

If anyone is familiar with this typeface, I'm glad to know.

Comment: The `cmm`, `cmr` etc are the default computer modern fonts. They (should) come with any LaTeX distribution.

Comment: Looks like linux libertine, or libertinus.

Comment: @mickep Hmm, seems `libertine` :)

Comment: Well, it does say so in the document properties … So it's a relatively safe bet :)

Comment: @Ingmar I though It would :(

Comment: TBH, there's about a dozen others in there. Quite an eclectic mix. Either way, the important thing is you now know the font …

Comment: The source of the paper is provided on arXiv https://arxiv.org/format/2110.08339 - it uses the acmart.cls, so I think libertine. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540011/font-used-in-acm-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capital `A` gives it away:
[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertinus}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

{\large\textbf{ABSTRACT}}

Notebooks provide an interactive environment for programmers 

\end{document}
```

Comment: This uses libertine package as  mickep & Dan MacKinnon mentioned. But both fonts seems not much difference for me. :)